# Convert a list of lists with different types into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to convert this list:

```
[[Chain(exchange='ABC', Id=123, Class='c1', expirations={'20180726', '20180830'}, strikes={1.1, 1.2})],
 [Chain(exchange='ABC', Id=345, Class='c2', expirations={'20180726', '20180830'}, strikes={0.5, 3.1, 2.8})]]
```

into a dataframe:

```
exchange     Id      Class    expirations    strikes
 --------    --      -----    -----------    -------
 ABC         123      c1      20180726       1.1
 ABC         123      c1      20180726       1.2

 ...

 ABC         345      c2      20180830       2.8
```

Chain is...

```
class Chain(builtins.tuple)
     |  Chain(exchange, Id, Class, expirations, strikes)
```

Is it possible using list comprehension and flattening?

Comment: Is possible add constructor for `Chain` to question?

Comment: Sorry, I try run code of list and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, some parts are missing. However, I tried a while and I produced this a bit messy code.

Sorry for that!

```
class Chain():    
    def __init__(self, exchange, Id, Class, expirations, strikes):
        self.exchange, self.Id, self.Class, self.expirations, self.strikes = exchange, Id, Class, expirations, strikes
        self.expirations = list(self.expirations)
        self.strikes = list(self.strikes)
    def merge(self):
        self.temp_list = []
        for index_1 in range(len(self.expirations)):
            for index_2 in range(len(self.strikes)):
                self.temp_list.append([self.exchange, self.Id, self.Class, 
    self.expirations[index_1], self.strikes[index_2]])
        return self.temp_list

    chain_1 = Chain(exchange='ABC', Id=123, Class='c1', expirations={'20180726', '20180830'}, strikes={1.1, 1.2}).merge()
    chain_2 = Chain(exchange='ABC', Id=345, Class='c2', expirations={'20180726', '20180830'}, strikes={0.5, 3.1, 2.8}).merge()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(chain_1+chain_2, columns=["exchange", "Id", "Class", "expirations", "strikes"])
df

Output:
exchange    Id  Class   expirations strikes
0   ABC     123     c1  20180726    1.1
1   ABC     123     c1  20180726    1.2
2   ABC     123     c1  20180830    1.1
3   ABC     123     c1  20180830    1.2
4   ABC     345     c2  20180726    0.5
5   ABC     345     c2  20180726    2.8
6   ABC     345     c2  20180726    3.1
7   ABC     345     c2  20180830    0.5
8   ABC     345     c2  20180830    2.8
9   ABC     345     c2  20180830    3.1
```

I hope this help!
Ceyhun

Comment: Thx @Ceyhun. The Chains are in a large list, so I cannot put them as chain_1...n. Also expirations and strikes are of type 'set', class and exchange are of type 'str' and Id is an 'int.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to create an iterator for Chain class, but I could not achieve. If you describe or show Chain class with more information, this can be very helpful. I am looking forward to see the answer.